# NGINX - Remove .html extension and add trailing slash

Tags: web-services, web, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to remove the `.HTML` extension from files in `NGINX`

```
server {
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
}
```

Now `website.com/privacy` is handled the same as `website.com/privacy.html` however `website.com/privacy/` will return `404`.

However, I want to rewrite `privacy.html` to `website.com/privacy/`

- Note trailing slash

Comment: `privacy.html` is a file but `website.com/privacy/` is a directory...The directory has to exists

Comment: @user2196728 Yes, I get that. However, if `/privacy/` is not an existing directory I want `NGINX` to handle it as `privacy.html`; in fact, I wouldn't even mind if it _skips_ the directory test. This is purely for prettified `URLs`.